# How to generate SOAP header in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I a new to SOAP. How can I generate SOAP header like the one below ?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <t:Transaction xmlns:t="xxs">
            <tc>
                <iden u="Test" p="TEMP001" city="code" role="Agent" />
                <agent user="user1" />
                <trace>trace001</trace>
                <script name="test" />
            </tc>
        </t:Transaction>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [SOAP module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) that can be compiled-in for dealing with SOAP communication.

One of the functions in the SOAP module is SoapHeader, which can be used to generate headers just like the one you described.

*Example Usage:*

```
$header = SoapHeader('http://namespace.example.com/',
                       'nameOfHeader',
                       'Data contained in header');
```

Check out this bit of the PHP manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php
for more about this function and the whole SOAP module in PHP (It's explained pretty well)

Hope this will be a useful resource for you,
Best of Luck!